# Ajax Broken in Browsers works in Android

Tags: ajax

I can run this code in Android app (using PhoneGap adn jQuery Mobile) but not on desktop browsers.
It gives me a syntax error in firebug for this line =

```
var TicketList = eval("(" + ajax.responseText + ")");
```

Here is the code

```
// JScript source code

// ran on body load
function doJsStuff()
{
    var ajax = AJAX();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            var TicketList = eval("(" + ajax.responseText + ")");
            if (TicketList.ListCount > 0) {
            document.getElementById("opencount").innerHTML = TicketList.ListCount +" Open Tickets";
                for (Ticket in TicketList.Tickets) {
                // add stuff to DOM
                //AddTicketToList(TicketList.Tickets[Ticket]);
                }
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("opencount").innerHTML = "All Tickets Reviewed";
                DisplayNoresults();
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET", "http://website.com/ListTicketsRequest.ashx?PageNumber=1&PageSize=1&Status=Open", true);
    ajax.send(null);
    //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
    //event to check for PhoneGap
    //$('ul').listview('refresh');
    $('#mtickets').page();
    //showVars();
}

function AJAX()
{
    var xmlHttp;
    try
    {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

**TicketList is a variable in the JSon that comes across like this=

```
{"Tickets" : [{"TicketID": "1054","Category": "N/A","SubmittedUserID": "bob.thebuilder","ShortDescription": "test question QID:16668","CreationDate": "2/16/2011 12:24:19 PM","TicketStatus": "Open","LongDescription": "Something is wrong with this question I know I hve the right answer but it keeps telling me I'm wrong"},{"TicketID": "1053","Category": "Mission Support","SubmittedUserID": "dave","ShortDescription": "Make  courseware revisions","CreationDate": "2/16/2011 9:34:48 AM","TicketStatus": "Open","LongDescription": "Find help tickets generated by users for possible courseware update."}], "PageCount": "6", "ListCount": "11"}
```

**Note about PhoneGap** If you are trying to include phoengap functions in a place where the code may also be executed on in a browser make sure you only add the phone gap function with on "deviceready" or your browser will not render. Example:

```
function onload(){
        //event to check for PhoneGap
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
...
function onDeviceReady() 
    {
        // Now PhoneGap API ready
        vibrate(90); // vib to ack pg ready
        $("a").click(function(event){
        vibrate(30); // add 30 sec vib to all links
        });         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My immediate response would be to use [jQuery's getJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), since you're aready using jQuery. jQuery's AJAX provides a much broader base of browser compatibility. Also, every time you use `eval()`, a small baby somewhere cries.

```
var url = "http://website.com/ListTicketsRequest.ashx?PageNumber=1&PageSize=1&Status=Open";

$.getJSON(url ,function(TicketList){
    if (TicketList.ListCount > 0) {
        $("#opencount").html(TicketList.ListCount +" Open Tickets");
        for (Ticket in TicketList.Tickets) {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        $("#opencount").html("All Tickets Reviewed");
        DisplayNoresults();
    }
});
```

If this still doesn't work for you, ensure that the JSON being returned is valid. But please stick to this method, and don't use `eval`!!

**SIMPLIFIED UPDATE**

```
var url = "http://website.com/ListTicketsRequest.ashx?PageNumber=1&PageSize=1&Status=Open";
$.getJSON(url ,function(AnyNameYouWant){
   alert(AnyNameYouWant.ListCount + " Open Tickets");
});
```

**UPDATE USING 'DATA'**

If your url becomes too long, you might begin to encounter problems. It is suggested to pass the url data via the `data` argument.

```
var url = "http://website.com/ListTicketsRequest.ashx";
var data = "PageNumber=1&PageSize=1&Status=Open";

$.getJSON(url, data, function(AnyNameYouWant){
   alert(AnyNameYouWant.ListCount + " Open Tickets");
});
```

Comment: OK so how do I replace eval()? Is function(TicketList){} supposed to parse the data somehow. BTW TicketList is a variable that looks like the above edit.

Comment: `function(TicketList){}` is not a function called TicketList. It is a generic function (with no name) that is passed a variable called `TicketList`. Put your code in that function and use the `TicketList` variable just as you would if you had eval'd it. The `.getJSON()` function takes care of the eval behind the scenes.

Comment: See my simplified example above.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. In the spirit of completeness, I added a simplified demo that uses the `data` argument for cases when your URL may be too long (passing too much data). Also, have a look at these other shorthand methods you can use since you have jQuery included. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems likely to me that the syntax error isn't in the code you posted, but instead is contained in the JSON object you're evaluating in ajax.responseText. Take a look at the data being returned by the AJAX request. Is it valid Javascript? Does the page you're calling return something different to desktop browsers vs mobile? Is there an error message where the JSON code should be?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: Is your app running on website.com? If not, Firefox is probably blocking the XMLHttpRequest from functioning properly. Firefox 3 and below block cross-site AJAX requests. [Firefox 3.5 seems to allow some exceptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control).

Comment: There actually was a cross site browser error as well so thanks for this suggestion. It now works in browsers.